# Catching error from multer using ".fields" property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

i cant seem to figure out how to catch error with multer using the ".fields" property. the user is supposed to upload 4 photos and so i use the .fields property upload to my mongodb database.

here is the file for my multer config called s-multer

```
// [REQURIE] //
const crypto = require('crypto')
const multer = require('multer')
const MulterGridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')
const path = require('path')


// [REQUIRE] Personal //
const config = require('../s-config')

module.exports = {
        upload: multer({
            storage: new MulterGridFsStorage({
                url: config.MONGO_URI,
        
                file: (req, file) => {
                    try {
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                                if (err) { return reject(err) }
                                
                                const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(
                                    file.originalname
                                )
            
                                resolve({
                                    filename: filename,
                                    bucketName: 'uploads'
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    } catch (err) { console.log('err', err) }
                },
            }),
    
            onError : function(err, next) { console.log('err', err) },
            
            limits: { fileSize: 50000 }
        }),
    }
```

here is my express route that the user sends a request too:

```
const multer = require('../../../s-multer')
router.post(
    '/create',
    multer.upload.fields(
        [
            { name: 'general_image1', maxCount: 1 },
            { name: 'pump_image1', maxCount: 1 },
            { name: 'pump_image2', maxCount: 1 },
            { name: 'pump_image3', maxCount: 1 },
        ]
    ),
    async (req, res) => {
        // do stuff here
    }
)
```

upon uploading a file that is larger than 50kb it throws an error in the server terminal but i do not know how to catch it and send it back to the user.

Comment: You can handle errors using the onError option:

app.post('/upload',[
  multer({
    dest    : './uploads/',
    onError : function(err, next) {
      console.log('error', err);
      next(err);
    }
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.status(204).end();
  }
]);
If you call next(err), your route handler (generating the 204) will be skipped and the error will be handled by Express.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
router.post(
    '/create',
    async (req, res, next) => {
        multer.upload.fields(
            [
                { name: 'general_image1', maxCount: 1 },
                { name: 'pump_image1', maxCount: 1 },
                { name: 'pump_image2', maxCount: 1 },
                { name: 'pump_image3', maxCount: 1 },
            ]
        )(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                    // SEND CAUGHT ERROR!
                    res.send(err)
                }
                else { next() }
            })
        },
        async (req, res) => {
            // do stuff here
        }
)
```